# Default font and cell padding when opening files in LibreOffice/OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice, csv, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice

I've seen solutions for setting a default font when creating new files. What about a default font (and cellpadding) when opening an existing CSV file? LibreOffice seems to always default to Liberation Sans 10 size, which I would like to change.

Answer (score 1):

This may be just partial answer to this long standing question.

From the question, the only thing that can be solved is the default font itself when opening an existing file (not necessarily CSV file). It is *not* possible for font size or cell padding, at least on my side.

### Set default font in LibreOffice 4.4

1. Open LibreOffice 4.4 from Application Menu (or command line is `libreoffice4.4`).
2. In the menu bar, click on **Tools** > **Options**.
3. In the left column, expand **+LibreOffice** menu and click **Fonts**.
4. In the right column, it will show **Replacement Table**. You need to enable it by selecting the checkbox for **Apply replacement table** below the greyed/washed out table.
5. Under the **Replacement Table**, for the left text field **Font:** select `Libration Sans` from the drop-down menu.
6. Under the **Replacement Table**, for the right text field **Replace with:** select `Droid Sans Mono` (or your font of choice) from the drop-down menu.
7. Beside the **Replace with:** text field, click on the green color check mark ✔ button to add the selections; The entry will be listed in table below it.
8. In that table below, under **Always** column, put another check mark ✔ by clicking once on the empty check box.
9. Finally, click **OK** button.

When next time you open any existing CSV file (again, could be other type of file) in LibreOffice, the font shown will appear as what you have specified in **step 6**.

Most importantly, make sure you know what font is used in the existing file you want to open in LibreOffice. Otherwise, you might be adding unnecessary fonts in the **Replacement Table**, which may force LibreOffice to check redundant fonts and may open the file slower than usual.

### Confusing part

After opening the existing file, the text field in left-most second toolbar (which shows `Font Name` on mouse hover), will still show the original default font i.e. Liberation Sans. But you can notice by yourself that the displayed font isn't.

### Adding more entries

You can add more alternative fonts in the **Replacement Table**, by repeating **step 5, 6, 7, 8** for each pair of replacement. You can even replace the non-existing font with any installed font on your system i.e. `Times New Roman` (not installed) replace with `Liberation Serif` (installed). It works.

In earlier LibreOffice/OpenOffice versions, I vaguely remember that the **Replacement table** had few entries by default, for replacing Windows fonts with Free software fonts. But the newer version has since make the table empty by default.

Perhaps that was when I use LibreOffice/OpenOffice on Windows back then.